# creating a reference document schema for mongoose and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hi i am new to mongodb i am learning it and implementing for one of my hobby project which is using node.js ,please help me a schema and query to do the below project.

i have a hospital where each and every patient details are registered at his first visit and for every visit i need to add a visit for  that patient by a reference like .

```
var patientschema=mongoose.schema(
                   {
                      objectid:"12345678"
                      patientname: string,
                      patientDOB:Date,
                      Gender:string,
                      registrationfee:number,
                      visits:[{objectid:1234},{objectid:5678}]
                   });
```

and visit schema is like

```
var visitschema = mongoose.schema({
                                   objectid:"1234",
                                   patientid:"12345678"
                                   visitdate:date,
                                   reason:string,
                                   consultingdoctor:string
                                   consultingfee:number                      
                                  });
```

please provide me a proper schema and and a queries to achieve this from a node.js application.

Comment: You don't write the actual value in refrences. You need to pass the ref field. Check this link. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: is there any example or sample application created ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the two schemas should look like these.

```
var patientschema=mongoose.schema(
{
  patientname: string,
  patientDOB:Date,
  Gender:string,
  registrationfee:number,
  visits:[{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Visit' }]
});

var visitschema = mongoose.schema(
{
   patientid:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Patient' }
   visitdate:date,
   reason:string,
   consultingdoctor:string
   consultingfee:number                      
}); 

var Visit  = mongoose.model('Visit', visitschema);
var Patient = mongoose.model('Patient', patientschema);
```

Now let us create new Patient Entry:

```
var p1 = new Patient({name: 'Some Name', patientDOB : '2016-11-11', Gender : 'male', registrationfee : 123});
```

Now you can add Visits to this patient.

```
var v1 = new Visit({patientid : p1._id, ... Fill Other Fields here });
```

Now when save this visit, thats where it will get interesting

```
v1.save(function(err, res){

});
```

Mongoose will internally append v1's ID to your patient Visits Array. You can later search them by.

```
Patient.find().populate('visits').exec(function(err, res){
    // Here the P1 with have array of Visits
});
```